# Stores default callback

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

on all my ajax requests, like grid data loading, Ext.Ajax.request ... I test if user is still connected. If not, the json response is different from I expect. If user is not connected, the return will be a json with `auth => false`. So everytime I get this, I want to have the same procedure : return to the login page.

How to do that, extend or refactor the load / ajax request callbacks ?

Thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should change your server to return 401 errors (Not Authorized). And then catch such error in global Ajax `requestexecption` event handler.

Comment: ok, but the question is, how to define global Ajax requestexception ?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682249/override-ext-data-connection-best-practice/9682966#9682966 - I posted code sample there