# extjs4 global network exception listener

Tags: extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I want to write a `listener` that will listen to all network requests errors, something like this :

```
Ext.Ajax.on('requestexception', function(conn, response, options) {
    if (response.status === 555) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('test', 'test');
    }
});
```

The above code works only for requests via `Ext.Ajax.request()`, how to rewrite it so it could work also for form submits, url not found error etc.

On server side I have Spring MVC that dispatches all requests and if there is any `error`, the response status of `555` is returned.

```
form.submit({
     url: dispatcher.getUrl('savePlanRequest'),
     //headers: {'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data; accept-charset=utf-8'},
     scope: this,
     method: 'GET',
     params: {
         scan: scan_id,
         attachments: attachments_id,
         parcels: parcels_id
     },
     success: function(form, action) {
         this.fireEvent('plansaved', this);
         Ext.Msg.alert(i18n.getMsg('success'), i18n.getMsg('gsip.view.plans.NewPlanForm.success_info'))
     },
     failure: function(form, action) {
         console.log('failure');
         //Ext.Msg.alert(i18n.getMsg('failure'), action.result.msg);
     }
 });
```

Comment: Can you try: `Ext.override(Ext.data.Connection, { 
        onComplete : function(request) {
            console.log( request );
            this.callParent ( arguments );
        }
    });`

Comment: Console logs only for successful requests. On my form submits it enters form submit failure clause and tries to decode json.

Comment: Sorry, I think I got your question wrong. I assume you have tried `Ext.Ajax.on( 'requestcomplete', ...)` but it didn't work? Could you share the code of how exactly you submit the form?

Comment: Question updated. When there is session timeout, each server request returns response status of 555. The problem is that if that happens the response is not json formatted. I want to catch the response globally and then based on status redirect to login page.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can try: `Ext.override( Ext.form.action.Submit, { handleResponse : function( response ) { console.log( response ); this.callParent ( arguments ); } });`

Comment: Thanks, i am able to globaly catch the response but the response does not have status (only responseText and responseXml) and this way i have to override both submit and standard Ext.Ajax.request. I will dig into it when i have time. You gave me good pointers where to search. Post your solution so i can accept.

Comment: No problems, as a side note, I'm using direct for all server calls, where it's dead easy to monitor all server responses for failure (just a few lines in the launch method of the application).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Ext.override( Ext.form.action.Submit, { 
    handleResponse : function( response ) {

        var form = this.form,
            errorReader = form.errorReader,
            rs, errors, i, len, records;

        if (errorReader) {
             rs = errorReader.read(response);
             success = rs.success;
             // Do something if success is false
        }

        this.callParent ( arguments ); 
    }
});
```

Have a look at [the source code](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/Submit.html#Ext-form-action-Submit) for the exact `handleResponse()` method from which I copied most of the code above.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you don't need to override anything. You can place a listener on the Ext.Ajax singleton like it is described here:

[Override Ext.data.Connection - Best Practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682249/override-ext-data-connection-best-practice)

Another option is to use the Ext.util.Observable.observe() function as described here:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?172269-Global-connection-handler-for-500-404-403-response-codes

```
Ext.util.Observable.observe(Ext.data.Connection);

Ext.data.Connection.on('requestexception', function(conn, response, options, eOpts) {
    //...handle it
});
```