# using ExtJS reader and writers without data stores

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

Is there a way to utilize the power of ExtJS's reader, writer, request, etc classes without stores? Like for generic Ajax requests? I'd like the ability to define a reader that can accept the "data structure" I use in my application's server responses, and execute functions on a global scale. For example, the ability that if at any time there is an error on the server, there can be a specific application code that the reader would interpret and build a window dialog with the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Reader and Writer are actually configs of Proxies, for which there's an Ajax version. You don't have to have a store to use proxies - you can use proxies 'manually' without a store.

Stores are used to link models with a set of records loaded from the server/local storage. They are also heavily used with grids, trees, dataviews etc. But if you insist not to use them - you may.

As for the second part of your question - regardless of which type of server communication you choose (Ajax / Rest / Direct), there's a way to catch exceptions from the server. For some, it is a bit trickier than others (see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626428/extjs4-global-network-exception-listener/11632962) on possible issues with Ajax). Although all of these can be solved rather easily if you delve a bit into the ExtJS library code. In my case I'm using direct and the something similar to the following (in application `launch()`) catches pretty much all server issues (you just need to make sure your server throws exceptions):

```
    Ext.direct.Manager.on('exception', function(e, provide, eOpts) {
        Ext.MessageBox.alert('Server Error', e.message);
    });
```

To do something similar with AJAX, you will have:

```
Ext.Ajax.on('requestcomplete', function( iConn, iResponse, iOptions, ieOpts ){
    // do something with iResponse here    
});
```

Comment: I was talking about more than just exceptions. For example, let's say the server sends a type code of 534 which is supposed to tell the client to prompt the user for an authorization code for the previous request.

Comment: Forgive me as I'm using PHP and Direct, so I probably don't fully see how this happens - what do you mean by 'the server sends'?

Comment: I meant in the AJAX response. See the responses in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787754/what-to-call-application-data-protocol-data-format-api

Comment: Oh! In that case, I've added an example on how to achieve this for Ajax responses.

Comment: Have a look at the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-event-requestcomplete)

Comment: Okay, so actually answer my question by telling me how to use a custom defined reader/writer for proxies in ajax requests that can also be used in stores.

Comment: I'm not sure our terms/understanding is on par. A reader maps a server response into model records; the model can be nested. I'm not sure this is exactly what you mean by "data structure". If your server always have the same structure/format in its responses and this structure does not correspond to any records, you don't need reader - just inspect the returned JSON yourself in its Object/Array form.